# hostapd-wpe not working but wireless adapter supports AP mode?

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, hostapd

Sorry if this has been asked already, but I just couldn't find any questions that had solutions which actually worked for me.

I've basically downloaded hostapd-wpe, patched it, ran `make` and everything. I've also configured hostapd-wpe.conf to ensure that the interface was set to wlan0. However, I still get this error when running `./hostapd-wpe hostapd-wpe.conf`:

```
root@kali $ ./hostapd-wpe hostapd-wpe.conf 
Configuration file: hostapd-wpe.conf
Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr 60:e3:27:0a:ba:3a and ssid "hostapd-wpe"
OpenSSL: tls_global_ca_cert - Failed to load root certificates error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
OpenSSL: pending error: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
OpenSSL: pending error: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
Failed to set TLS parameters
Interface initialization failed
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
wlan0: AP-DISABLED 
wlan0: Unable to setup interface.
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
```

I'm a little uncertain as to why, because when I run `iw list` it shows "AP" under the supported modes.

I've already tried running `airmon-ng check kill` and similar commands, but it's still giving me this hard time.

Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm using a TP-LINK TP-WN722N wireless USB adapter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forget to build the certirficates that are needed by hostapd-wpe.
look in your log:

```
OpenSSL: tls_global_ca_cert - Failed to load root certificates error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
OpenSSL: pending error: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
OpenSSL: pending error: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

Since there are no certificate files, hostapd-wpe will not start!

Comment: This answer would be much improved by [edit]ing to provide instruction as to how the OP can accomplish building the certificates